# Azure Just-In-Time access: How to request Just-In-Time access outside of Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I've configured Just-In-Time access for my VM in Azure and it works. However, every time I have to go to Azure Portal to request the Just-In-Time access, is there any alternative to Azure Portal to request the Just-In-Time access?

[image]

How to request Just-In-Time access outside of Azure Portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

You can make use of PowerShell command Request Just-In-Time access like below:

```json
$JitPolicy = (@{    
     id="/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/RGNAME/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VMNAME";
     ports=(@{
          number=22;
          protocol="*";
          allowedSourceAddressPrefix=@("*");
          maxRequestAccessDuration="PT3H"},
          @{
          number=3389;
          protocol="*";
          allowedSourceAddressPrefix=@("*");
          maxRequestAccessDuration="PT3H"})})
```

Connect with PowerShell environment to your azure ad After that create a ***Jit policy*** like below:

[image]

The port 22 and 3389 for rdp access will have ***maximum request access duration of three hours***;

- `$JitPolicyArr=@($JitPolicy)`

```json
 Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy -Kind "Basic" -Location "EastUS" -Name "default" -ResourceGroupName "RGNAME" -VirtualMachine $JitPolicyArr
```

Then `Set-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy` cmd you can request creation of new Jit policy of this machine.

[image]

You can see ***new security center Jit rule with port was deny*** and blocked from outside of azure like below:

[image]

Now, you can raise a request just in time access using below commend:

```json
$JitPolicyVm1 = (@{    id="/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/VMNAME";
        ports=(@{
           number=22;
           endTimeUtc="2022-12-13T17:00:00.3658798Z";
           allowedSourceAddressPrefix=@("IPV4ADDRESS")})})

$JitPolicyArr=@($JitPolicyVm1)

Start-AzJitNetworkAccessPolicy -ResourceId "/subscriptions/SUBSCRIPTIONID/resourceGroups/RESOURCEGROUP/providers/Microsoft.Security/locations/LOCATION/jitNetworkAccessPolicies/default" -VirtualMachine $JitPolicyArr
```

[image]

Now, the request access has been created in the azure portal and allow port 22 for ip address like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of this ***reference***:

[Automate Just In Time VM Access Request with PowerShell](https://charbelnemnom.com/automate-just-in-time-vm-access-request-with-powershell-azuresecuritycenter-azuresecurity-asc-powershell/)  by *Charbel nemnom*

[Enabling and Scripting Azure Virtual Machine Just-In-Time Access – Kloud Blog](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/07/24/enabling-and-scripting-azure-virtual-machine-just-in-time-access/) by *Darren Robinson*